# Use connectionString from Web.config in a Windows Service Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services, web-config, connection-string

I am currently trying to build a Windows Service Application that will send mails automatically. The database is in the `MVC3` Project under the `APP_DATA` Folder. My question now is, how can I use the connectionString from the `web.config` in my Windows Service application to run querys at a specific time and send automatically mails to the user when the queries are not empty. I did some research but I didn't found any solutions. Is this approach even possibile? Thanks in advance

Comment: Umm, if you're building a WINDOWS service, why exactly you're trying to use WEB.config? Maybe that's why you didn't find any resources to learn from.

Comment: @walther I acutally want to query the database which is in my ASP.NET MVC3 Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows Service will be executed as a separate application and has no direct access to the configuration of your web application. I would suggest you to build a web service in your web application and provide necessary APIs.

Then you can use your Windows Service to call Web Service methods and retrieve your necessary data.

EDIT:
MSDN is the best resource to educate from. You can start from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: Do you have any links for me where I could educate myself on?

Answer (score 0):

To a connection you can use:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Tried this. It's not working and it's throwing an exception. C:\User\Superbyte\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\nin\Debug\DRMS_DB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located to UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

your windows service uses an app.config file and not a web.config file.
right click on your windows service project and select add new item on the context menu then look for Application Configuration File and click add. Copy your connection strings from the web.config file on the website and paste it in the app.config file of your windows service.
alternatively you could create an API like that Ihor Deyneka suggested

Comment: When I copy the connectionString from the web.config to the App.config I get a SqlException telling me the following: 
An Attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\User\Superbyte\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\nin\Debug\DRMS_DB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located to UNC share.

Comment: your windows service is looking for the DRMS_DB.mdf you need to attach this database file to your project. this is not the ideal way to solve  your problem. you should look at creating a separate project for data access and reference it in your various projects.... here are some links on how to create n-tier applications  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973279.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384570.aspx,  http://geekswithblogs.net/edison/archive/2009/04/05/a-simple-3-tier-layers-application-in-asp.net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try application configuration file in place of your web.config file? If not try it and use the same code for reading connection string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your Connection String Name"].ConnectionString;
```